# Why array of objects is showing blank in firebug though it contain items - Javascript + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, firebug

Following is the screenshot, I am unable to trace what is going wrong here with JavaScript.

If you see that the array in firebug is showing a blank array and if I console the length it is also coming `0`. BUT if I click the (+) icon its showing the data. Let me know what I am doing wrong with the code.

**Code -**

```
            //scope.days is an array of objects
            var newArr = [];
            var myArr = [];
            myArr = scope.days;
            console.log(myArr.length);
            var weekNum = 1;
            newArr['week'+weekNum] = [];
            for(var i=1; i<= myArr.length; i++) {
                newArr['week'+weekNum].push(myArr[i]);
                if(i%7 == 0){
                    weekNum = weekNum + 1;
                    newArr['week'+weekNum] = [];
                }
            }
            scope.days = newArr;
```

**Firebug Screenshot -**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's helpful to understand that objects can be accessed using either bracket or dot notation. Also note that *Arrays are also objects*.

So `myObj` with a property `myProp` can be accessed using either `myObj["myProp"]`  or `myObj.myProp`. Square bracket notation is useful when we want to dynamically access a property but we don't know it's identifier at design time. i.e. we want to use a dynamically created label:

```
var label = "myProp";
myObj[label] = "xyz";
```

So the point of the above is that square bracket notation is a means to reference `properties` of an object. In your code you do this:

```
newArr['week'+weekNum] = [];
```

apparently with the intent of using `'week'+weekNum` as an index into the array, but instead what it is actually doing is making a property assignment. So you can  continue to make `'week'+weekNum` all week long and array length will still be zero because you are not assigning elements to the array but instead generating new properties.

What you likely want is just

```
newArr[weekNum] = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

An `Array` is indexed from `0` and up. Your array contains no items. Although it does have properties.

You're using it like an `Object`. If you were to define it as such (`newArr = { }`), Firebug would have a better idea of how to render it.

Comment: but I defined newArr as Array // var newArr = []; or var myArr = []; and if you see I am assigning array of objects `myArr = scope.days;` and doing a console in for loop is showing the items, but don't know why it is not coming in the bottom where I am consoling the final array...how could I make this working ?